# Is it normal that my heated bed has up to 25 °C difference from center to edge?

Tags: temperature, bed, ender3

I have an Ender 3 V2 pro with the Quinly bed adhered to the aluminium bed.

I have a hard time getting my prints to stick well. (PLA as well as PETG). We finally found out that only increasing the bed temperature a lot helps a little. Only the edges have a very bad adhesion and even terrible warp.

Here are measurements from an infrared thermometer:

[image: temp in °C in different measurements]

I kept the orientation and distance constant.

1. Is it normal that the temperature has such differences across the bed?
2. If not: What could be the cause?
3. And: How can this be solved?

Comment: Are these 8 measurement sessions of the bed (of a single heating event), in different resolutions (9, 16 and 25 points) or separate heating cycles? A temperature of 86 °C is pretty high for PLA or PETG, if it doesn't adhere, you may need an adhesive or place the nozzle closer to the bed. Is the bed insulated at the bottom?

Comment: I started off at 60°C, but as big prints tend to warp I tried increasing the temp and ended up here. The temperature we use for PLA (60°C) also shows the same signs of uneven distribution. Also, my bed is the Quinly VAARP, they recommend 65-85°C for PETG. The measurements are at different days and different cycles. The Ender3 v2 has no insulation at the bottom.